# How to efficiently extract a subset of a cv::Mat

Tags: c++, opencv

A common thing to do in machine learning is to have the first column of a dataset represent the class that the corresponding row belongs to for a data point.

Basically, I have a cv::Mat and I want to efficiently create a cv::Mat containing that matrix with the first column removed.  Is there a more efficient way of doing this than looping over the columns and rows and adding the elements one by one with `mat.at<data_type>(row, col) = elem;` ?

Comment: you certainly would use the MatIterator to iterate over the matrix!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [Mat::operator()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#id4) from OpenCV documentation.

Comment: see also the function `colRange()`. Remember, that this just creates a new header for the very same data (no copy is involved). You can copy the submatrix, e.g. using `clone()`, though.

Comment: I agree with @moooeeeep. Look at `rowRange()` and `colRange()`.

Comment: NOTE: Mat::operator()'s documentation has moved slightly, to http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#id6